# Use of "liberal" in this context

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Is the word "liberal" used properly in the following paragraph?

> My school is very liberal. In fact, some of the English teachers in my
>   school gave a student an E for using Donald trump as an example to
>   their essay.

Comment: An E is a good grade or a bad grade?

Comment: @Andrew - a bad grade.

Comment: Ah ok.  An E would not be familiar in the US.

Comment: @user31264 If you changed E -> F, I think everyone would understand you without substantially changing the quote.

Comment: This is actually quite an interesting question, as it counterpoints the two different meanings of liberal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. It is using "[liberal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/liberal)" as an adjective to modify "school". The meaning is in the sense of a political viewpoint that is accepting of and respects other people's ideas and behaviour, even if they differ from their own.

Donald Trump is an example of a conservative, and is often seen as being the opposite of a liberal, strongly opposing liberalism. Therefore, those with a liberal viewpoint tend to dislike him.

While the act of "punishment" described is *not* liberal, someone may be described as "liberal" without being liberal in *all* things. They may see themselves as promoting "liberalism" by criticising/marginalising Donald Trump. The *actions* of someone who is liberal may not all be considered liberal, especially if it is in opposition to something or someone illiberal. For example, a liberal might espouse freedom of speech as an inalienable right, but strongly criticise, or even attempt to silence someone for saying something racist or homophobic.

Additionally, if this was meant as a joke, the dichotomy of a "liberal" doing something "illiberal" would be what made it funny.

Alternatively, the "school" could refer to the school *authorities*, which are being liberal in allowing their teachers to grade essays however they want.

Comment: Isn't giving students low grades for their perceived political views  constitute something opposite of "accepting of and respects other people's ideas and behaviour"?

Comment: @user31264 yes definitely but by "liberal" you might mean "liberal bias".

Comment: @user31264 Yes, you are correct, the action of "punishment" described is not liberal. However, someone may be described as "liberal" without being liberal in _all_ things. They may see themselves as promoting "liberalism" by criticising Donald Trump.

Comment: @user31264 Also, if this was meant as a joke, the fact that the action of the teachers was _not_ liberal would be the thing making it funny.

Comment: If this is intended to be a joke, it's a pretty lame joke.

Comment: @J.R. That's why I said "If"... Maybe I should put "funny" in quotes :P.

Comment: If *liberal* is intended to be a political leaning, should it be capitalised? That is, *Liberal* vs *Conservative*. (I'm not very familiar with American politics.)

Comment: @Lawrence No, I don't think so unless you are talking about (membership or support of) a particular political party or entity, e.g. the Liberal Party. That said, I am British, so I may be wrong.

Comment: @SteveES Yes, that makes sense. But in the case of a *liberal school*, does *liberal* necessarily have political overtones? I'm asking because if *E* was close to *fail* rather than *Excellent*, I would have answered *no* to the OP's question, along the lines of your answer's closing note (regarding *illiberal*).

Comment: @Lawrence "Liberal" would not _have_ to have "political" overtones. The second sentence could equally well have been "The teachers never tell off any of the students." or "A student literally got away with murder.".

Comment: @SteveES I see your point now. The *liberal* label is applied to the *teachers* - the school allows teachers to grade opinion-based answers as they wish. (Contrast this with a *liberal school* that applies *liberal* to the students, in which case it would be incongruous to mark down *any* opinion-based answer.)

Answer (score 0):

The word liberal is used correctly here that is fine.

However, "using Donald trump as an example **to** their essay" should be "using Donald trump as an example **for** their essay.